# Installing Lenovo Internet drivers after Windows 7 upgrade

Tags: windows-7, networking, drivers, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad W520 (4270) that I just upgraded to Window 7 Ultimate x64. After the upgrade I couldn't connect to the internet and found out that I have no adapters (wireless or Ethernet).

What drivers do I need to download and install from Lenovo? I've been looking under the Networking: WWAN, Networking: Wireless LAN, and Wireless according tabs for the correct wireless driver and Networking: Ethernet for the correct Ethernet driver.Is there a way that I can lookup the hardware components that I have to narrow down what drivers I need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always liked using [ThinkVantage System Update](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-61432#update) to automatically download all required drivers for my Thinkpads.

I'm not really sure if that software works for all Thinkpads though.

**edit**: I guess I kinda missed your point with my answer, so I looked into it again. According to this [datasheet](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/ww/pdf/w520_datasheet.pdf), your ThinkPad has either of these WLAN chips:

- Intel
  ®
  Centrino
  ®
  Ultimate-N  6300    (Puma   Peak)   3x3 AGN     (performance)
- Intel
  ®
  Centrino
  ®
  Advanced-N  6205    (Taylor     Peak)   2x2 AGN     (performance)

This [download page](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&DocID=HT063273) lists 3 drivers. The first seems to be for the Intel
®
    Centrino
®
    Advanced-N  +   WiMAX   6250    (Kilmer     Peak)   2x2 AGN. Which is listed in the datasheet under WiMAX/Wifi (whatever that means). That only leaves one download from Intel. I'd go with that one.

How to actually determine what hardware is built into your ThinkPad? Apart from opening it up and looking for printed labels on the chips, I have no idea.

Comment: Looks like I need to get the driver for my wireless card so I can access the internet first since it pulls all the needed drivers,BIOS, etc. from the lenovo servers over the internet

Comment: @Ben Sorry for kinda missing the point of your question. I updated my answer with, hopefully, more relevant information.

Comment: -1. Installing drivers from INFs makes sure [that the drivers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/05/84469.aspx) [won’t do nasty things](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/08/16/452141.aspx).

Comment: There are 3 drivers on Lenovo's support pages to choose from. I finally just took the keyboard off and looked at what card I have in order to choose the correct driver to download.